# Cómo puedo actualizar datos Crystal Reports en .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo actualizar esos campos? Lo que pasa es que necesito cambiar el nombre de unos campos y agregar otro, pero no sé cómo actualizarlo para que aparezcan en **Visual Studio**

Comment: especifica mas tu pregunta, aun esta muy ambigua

Comment: Creo que debería cambiar el titulo de la pregunta a: `Cómo puedo actualizar el origen de datos en Crystal Reports .NET?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado lo que entendí sobre tu pregunta:

Me parece que has realizado ciertos cambios en la tabla `Nomina` de la base de datos, y estos no se reflejan en los campos de la tabla del `Visual Studio`.

Para esto siga los siguientes pasos:

1- Diríjase a su Explorador de Campo `Field Explorer`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2- Dar click derecho sobre `Database Fields`, y luego dar click en `Verify Database`, si su conexión actual es correcta esto actualizará su conjunto de datos y tendrá los campos actualizados en su Visual Studio (Luego le muestra un cuadro de dialogo indicando que se actualizó):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Puede verificar esto si se dirige a su `Database Expert`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que esto sería todo, espero le sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la conección de base de datos de tu reporte. Si este está tomando una tabla de tu base de datos, pues tendras que editarla primero. O sí este se realiza desde otro arhivo, la edición la realizaras en el archivo de dataset, no sobre el que muestra la plantilla de reporte.

Sobre tu dataset, Nomina, click derecho y selecciona verificar tu base de datos. Eso actualiza el dataset con los últimos cambios. En ocasiones esto provocará que quitar las propiedades del dataset en la plantilla. tendrás que volverlos a incluirlos.

Comment: pero que pasa, porque si hago eso me apece una ventana que dice que ponga una clase, y si entendi tu explicacion eso no deberia salir o si?

Comment: Entonces actualiza desde la ventana de base de datos, ahí mismo donde seleccionas los dataset.